# Why Timer is not working when I publish my new web application?

Tags: vb.net

I created a timer in a form, VB.NET web application. The timer works perfect on my developing server but when I publish the application  the timer does not work.So it seems that is not triggering. Have you seen this before ?

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        AE_Report_Timer.Enabled = True
        AE_Report_Timer.Interval = 20000 ' in milisecondsseconds
.
.
.    
 End Sub

 Protected Sub AE_Report_Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AE_Report_Timer.Tick
       Information.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyy hh:mm:ss")

        Page_Load(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub
```

.
.
.

Comment: Timer in the web application are executed on the server. It's possible that the application/session got reset or that the server doesn't even allow it. It is usually not a wise decision to have a server timer on a web application. Based on your code, it seems like it would be better to have it in javascript instead.

Comment: Timers are not blocking, so by the time that your timer has elapsed, the given page request which started the timer should have already rendered the HTML and streamed the response down to the client.